# How to check over what element my mouse is when I lose focus on input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this:

```
<body>
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction()" />

<... rest of page ...>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction()
    {
        //this function alerts over what element your mouse is when the input loses focus
    }
</script>
```

Does someone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could track what element your mouse if hovering over, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onblur="myFunction()" />
```

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInput'), // Get the input element
    focus;

input.onmouseover = input.onfocus = function(){focus = true;}; // Set focus to true if the input gains focus
input.onmouseout = input.onblur = function(){focus = false}; // Set focus to false if the input loses focus

document.body.onmousemove = function(e){
    if(!focus){ // Only log the target is the input doesn't have focus
        console.log(e.target); //Log the current element the mouse is hovering over.
    }
};
```

As far as I know, there's no accurate way to check the mouse's current target on the `"mouseleave"` or `"blur"` events, since the `event.target` of those functions will point to the element the mouse just left, not to the element the mouse is currently hovering over.

**Edit:**
I added some code so it only logs when the input doesn't have focus.

Comment: Nice implementation there. I only needed to delete the part with "input.onmouseout" since I dont want my element to loose focus on mouseout :). All in all it works pretty well : ) thanks